# OpenCV - "Invalid paramater" when iterating through a vector

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I'm trying to iterate through a vector of image path, read them with the cv::imread function, and then use the format_signal function on the resultant cv::Mat.

```
#include "tp1.hpp"

using ImagePathFlag = std::pair<std::string, int>; 

int main(int /*argc*/, char** /*argv*/) {
    try {
        const std::vector<ImagePathFlag> vsTestImages = {
            { "data/test1.png",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE },
            { "data/test2.png",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE },
            { "data/test3.png",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE },
            { "data/test4.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test5.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test6.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test7.png",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test8.jpg",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test9.bmp",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
            { "data/test10.bmp",cv::IMREAD_COLOR },
        };
        for (const ImagePathFlag& oImagePathFlag : vsTestImages) {
            std::cout << oImagePathFlag.first << std::endl;
            cv::Mat oInputImg = cv::imread(oImagePathFlag.first, oImagePathFlag.second);
            if (oInputImg.empty())
                CV_Error_(-1, ("Could not load image at '%s', check local paths", oImagePathFlag.first.c_str()));

            std::vector<uint8_t> signal = format_signal(oInputImg);


        }
    }
    catch (const cv::Exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught cv::Exceptions: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "Caught std::runtime_error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Caught unhandled exception." << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The format_signal and lz77_encode seems to work fine the first iteration or the for loop, but at the end of this first iteration, the programm crashes with the following error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE6E5D4388 (ucrtbase.dll) in
>   inf4710_tp1.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that
>   considers invalid parameters fatal.

Not quite sure what's happening here. I admit that I don't fully understand the syntax of the for loop, as it was provided by my teacher.

Any help?

**EDIT**

```
inline std::vector<uint8_t> format_signal(const cv::Mat& oInputImage) {
    CV_Assert(!oInputImage.empty() && oInputImage.isContinuous() && (oInputImage.type() == CV_8UC1 || oInputImage.type() == CV_8UC3));

    std::vector<uint8_t> vSignal;
    cv::imencode(".png", oInputImage, vSignal);
    return vSignal;
}
```

Comment: Off topic: You got modern C++ code from a teacher? By Crom! There is hope for the future!

Comment: The problem is certainly in `lz77_encode`; either a buffer overrun, or some other form of stack corruption. Hard to say without seeing the source.

Comment: The problem is still here even if I don't call lz77_encode in the main. I edited my code to show this.

Answer (score 0):

> I admit that I don't fully understand the syntax of the for loop

You are using a range-based for loop available in C++11 and beyond. It iterates over each item in your vector of pairs. 
Have you debugged your problem? If so, can you share what you have seen so far? What does your format_signal do? Does everything work correctly in that function?

Comment: 1. Are you building your application with debug symbols? If so, can you run your app through gdb/lldb/other debugger and look at the stack trace? Another thing to check is to comment out the call to format_signal to see if that function is the source of your error. I do not have OpenCV 3.0 available, so I can't repro your issue. I would love to but I can't change my setup.